# ArcGIS HDF File Display Error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, hdf

When I open a HDF file in ArcMap, the display of HDF file is shown as Fig.1. The HDF file has many bands, Arcmap will popups the window when open the HDF file regularly.

However, there is no pop-up window  when I open HDF file in the Arcmap software and the display is shown as Fig.1. I don't know the reason for the error. Have anyone encountered the error before?[image]

```
                                          Fig.1
```

Now,I think it a lot,maybe the popup window failed to be opened,so the ArcMap just opened the first band of HDF file.If it is true, how I make the popup window be opened?

Comment: I think you may have forgotten to insert a picture.  In any event please always include error messages as text rather than pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem,because the subdataset selection window is not be popuped.

In **Customize** drop-down list of menu bar, selecting **ArcMap Options** window, then navigate to ***Raster*** Tabs, to tick before ***Prompt for subdataset selection***.

[image]